# Lua-Sqlite3 get "rowid"

Tags: sql, sqlite, lua, row, coronasdk

When I run the **code**:

```
row = db:first_row("SELECT MIN(rowid) from table")
local minID = row.rowid

row = db:first_row("SELECT MAX(rowid) from table")
local maxID = row.rowid
```

I get an error saying:

```
Runtime error: ...\db_test\main.lua:33: attempt to call method 'first_row' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'first_row'
    ...\main.lua:33: in main chunk
```

That exact same SQL query works in Python on the same database.

From the [sqlite documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html)

"ROWIDs and the INTEGER PRIMARY KEY

Every row of every SQLite table has a 64-bit signed integer key that uniquely identifies the row within its table. This integer is usually called the "rowid". The rowid value can be accessed using one of the special case-independent names "rowid", "oid", or "*rowid*" in place of a column name."

#### For anyone interested, the working code in my case is:

```
local minId
local maxId
for row in db:nrows("SELECT MIN(rowid) AS `rowmin` FROM " .. table) do
    minId = row.rowmin
end
for row in db:nrows("SELECT MAX(rowid) AS `rowmax` FROM " .. table) do
    maxId = row.rowmax
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the [lua-sqlite3](http://lua.sqlite.org/) wrapper, you'd need to iterate using [**`db:rows()`**](http://lua.sqlite.org/index.cgi/doc/tip/doc/lsqlite3.wiki#db_rows) method and not the `first_row`. The call will be:

```
row = db:rows("SELECT MIN(rowid) AS `rowmin`, MAX(rowid) AS `rowmax` FROM table")
local minID, maxID = row.rowmin, row.rowmax
```

---

Based on @CL 's suggestion in comments:

```
row = db:rows("SELECT MIN(rowid) AS `rowmin` FROM table")
local minID = row.rowmin
row = db:rows("SELECT MAX(rowid) AS `rowmax` FROM table")
local maxID = row.rowmax
```

Comment: Please note that SQLite's optimizer can do a better job if you use separate queries for the `MIN` and `MAX` values.

Comment: Works, Thanks! Strange that you can't get a single row though and also that it only works if you select rowid AS something else. You mind explaining why?

Comment: @JaredGlass If you don't use the `AS` selector, then your table key would be accessed like: `row["MAX(rowid)"]`. I used `AS` to shorten the later segment.